# Ошибка при интеграции Flurry

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

При интеграции Flurry и подключения всех библиотек выдает ошибку при запуске
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

С чем может быть связанно?

Comment: Была похожая история, починил так: откройте `Pods project` - `Build Settings`, далее`Build Active Architecture Only` если текст выделин жирным шрифтом, нажмите на него и затем нажмите `backspace`.

Comment: Так же посмотрите http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24519051/library-not-found-with-cocoapods

Comment: Спасибо помогли

Comment: Какой из двух советов Вам помог?